# ViewmodelBuilders for viewmodels with properties to other viewmodels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm using a ViewModelBuilder-class to map my models to ViewModels.

Problem is, when I try to build viewmodels for the Projects property I use a viewmodelbuilder for that too and THAT viewmodelbuilder's model has a reference back to Account which it will also try to map to a viewmodel. Result is stackoverflowexeption.

How to solve this?
I thought of sending a bool to the mapping functions, but then I will lose mapping of some nested properties that i **do** want to map.

Very thankful for any advice I could get!

```
public class AccountViewModelBuilder : IViewModelBuilder<AccountViewModel, Account>
{

    protected AllViewModelBuilders _allViewModelBuilders { get; private set; }

    public AccountViewModelBuilder(AllViewModelBuilders allViewModelBuilders)
    {
        _allViewModelBuilders = allViewModelBuilders;
    }

    public AccountViewModel BuildFromEntity(Account entity)
    {
        return new AccountViewModel()
        {
            ID = entity.ID,
            Name = entity.Name,
            //Projects = _allViewModelBuilders.ProjectViewModelBuilder.BuildFromEntity(entity.Projects).ToList()
        };
    }

    public Account BuildFromViewModel(AccountViewModel viewModel, Account entity)
    {

        if (entity == null) return null;

        entity.Name = viewModel.Name;
        //entity.Projects = _allViewModelBuilders.ProjectViewModelBuilder.BuildFromViewModel(viewModel.Projects).ToList();

        return entity;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AccountViewModel> BuildFromEntity(ICollection<Account> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
            yield return BuildFromEntity(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Account> BuildFromViewModel(ICollection<AccountViewModel> viewModels)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit**
So i decided to go with AutoMapper, with some extensions...

```
public static class ConditionExtensions
{
    public static void IgnoreIfSourceIsNull<T>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<T> expression)
    {
        expression.Condition(IgnoreIfSourceIsNull);
    }

    static bool IgnoreIfSourceIsNull(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (!context.IsSourceValueNull)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var result = context.GetContextPropertyMap().ResolveValue(context.Parent);
        return result.Value != null;
    }
}

public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
        var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType.Equals(sourceType)
            && x.DestinationType.Equals(destinationType));


        foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
        {
            expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
        return expression;
    }



    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ProjectViewModel, Project>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<LogbookUser, RegisterViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<RegisterViewModel, LogbookUser>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<Account, AccountViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AccountViewModel, Account>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<FileGroup, FileGroupViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<FileGroupViewModel, FileGroup>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<AttachedFile, AttachedFileViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<AttachedFileViewModel, AttachedFile>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, Customer>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());

        Mapper.CreateMap<WorkOrder, WorkOrderViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        Mapper.CreateMap<WorkOrderViewModel, WorkOrder>().IgnoreAllNonExisting().ForAllMembers(c => c.IgnoreIfSourceIsNull());
    }
}
```